# How to Sort unique Contacts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, sorting, spreadsheet

I have a list of 35k contacts, I need to sort unique after unique

I demonstrated in this example how I want to sort contacts:

[image: Example]

I tried by removing duplicates then to copy unique and to go back to compare with original file, but that process takes time and it's not easy.

Comment: You need to explain ***a lot clearer*** what you want to do. I thought I understood it at first glance, but then I noticed that “51” appears twice in the “1st Unique” sublist, and “3” ***doesn’t*** appear in the “3st Unique” sublist, although it appears three times in the “A” list.  And what order are the sublists in?  It looks like the “1st Unique” sublist is in the same order as the “A” list, with “2” and “4” after the two-digit numbers.  But why is “4” before “5”?  Why is “1” before “3” in the “2st Unique” sublist? … (Cont’d)

Comment: P.S. Number 2 (the one after the first one) is called second and abbreviated “2nd”, and #3 is third (“3rd”).

Answer (score 0):

On cell B2, type this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B18,$A$2:$A$18),0))
```

and copy it to the rest of the column. This will create a list with no duplicates on column B. To simplify, name this array `list`. Then, use this formula on column C:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,list)>=2,list,"")
```

This creates the list with only the values that appear 2 times or more.
Copy this formula to other columns and change the 2 to 3, 4 etc to create a list with the values that appear only 3, 4 etc or more times.

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, with these I don't know to try,
I will send one of demo file, and if you can put the formula and I'll check that, I want to sort by unique "domain" colon and all from that colon to sort all of the contacts, as you did above,

Hope you understand I don't need only one category I need all of them but if we sort by unique domain,1st unique than 2 unique under 1st one. 
So later I can filter them to show all of them, (all colons)

Hope It's clear

File - > https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNA7ShiFE7LRUp2anhPSHZKVHc/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Actually, what you are asking is much simpler than the question you posted. You can just add filters to your table and sort them, first by the Domain column and then sort the Name columns

Comment: please can you help me that file to send me back if you can sort, I don't understand you, when you say that is much simpler, I'm trying more than a week to find a way, can you add me on fb.com/edin.neziri, I will be very shortly, please, thank you

Comment: Check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654) and see how sorting data works. All you have to do is sort first by the "Domain" column and then by the "Name" column.

Comment: thank you for helping me, I put the filter table and now my question is how to filter the "domain" colon and then colon name?  by A-Z or how?
1st the "domain"?
then the "name"?

Comment: Yes, exactly like. Sort by A-Z, 1st the domain and 2nd the name.

Comment: if I sort domain A-Z it's going to be a lot of duplicates there also why to sort by name? it's going to mix all of them I need part by part 1st domains unique then 2d unique domains like in the 1st pic !?
1st and second can have duplicates but not 1st one every each should be unique! do you mean this? please if you can add me on fb and I will explain better, thank you

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do. Why do you need a unique list of Domain? What is the problem of having two different Names with the same Domain? That is actually the way to organize data in an Excel Table.

Comment: I need to be like the pic you provided but I have lots of columns, and when I sort for unique values I need the other data not to change. For example" If C3 is a unique value, I need A3, B3, D3 not to change from C3. Data are Just like the Pic below https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v2nV.jpg

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem of just sorting them?

Comment: look at this video I did very manually I need this process faster because I have 8k/sheet so If I will start doing like in a video at will take like forever.

Video - https://streamable.com/5z8d9